# create user in wso2 mobilty manager 1.1.0

Tags: registration, invite

Could someone explain me how to invite new user to wso2 mobility manager on 1.1.0 version. All documentation which I found is for 1.0.0 version, and there is invite button, in user management. on this version there is no such a button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything is documented [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Registering+a+Device) under version 1.1.0.